# StackOverFlow Website tags' search

Tags: support, tags, search

Say I have selected 3 tags on Stack Overflow: [php](/questions/tagged/php), [python](/questions/tagged/python), [java](/questions/tagged/java). I want to remove the [python](/questions/tagged/python) tag from the general search. What do I do?

Note: not while creating a question, but searching for questions.

Comment: why not just click on the question tag then click  the x by python to remove the tag, click on question tab, and when done add the python tag back?

Comment: you... don't... type... them? There's either a misunderstanding or a miscommunication happening here. What exactly are you doing to "select tags" when you search?

Comment: Do you want something like `(php OR java) AND NOT python`?

Comment: I was overlooking the search textbox. Selecting a tag was actually adding it to the text. But, I am also wondering if @"Rocket Hazmat" mentioned is possible.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Whoever added the little 'x' next to the tags. It is now easier to delete the tag from the search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a minus before the tag

```
[php] -[python] [java] some_search_term
```

to search for questions tagged with [java](/questions/tagged/java) and [php](/questions/tagged/php) but **not** with [phyton](/questions/tagged/phyton).

It is the same as with normal search terms ([general search options](https://stackoverflow.com/search))

Comment: You mean in the search text?

Comment: Yes, in the search box.